# DataTables - Get ID from span in Cell-Data

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) and in this table is a cell, which contains multiple `span`-Elements, like this one:

```html
<span class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-room="1910" data-id="1" disabled>
  <strong>unimportant description</strong>
</span>
```

I've just put the content of the cell into a variable:

```
var extras = roomstable.cell(closestRow,3).data();
```

How can I filter out the IDs in the `data-id`-Tags to put it into an Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is to extract multiple buttons id's within a cell into an array, you would rather need to employ [`cell().node()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().node()) method instead of `cell().data()`.

That would let you grab all the buttons, turn that set [`toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) and extract `data-id` attribute values:

```
var extras = $(roomstable.cell(closestRow,3).node())
   .find('span.btn')
   .toArray()
   .map(span => $(span).attr('data-id'));
```

Comment: yeah, thanks! It works. I just inserted the `)` that you forgot at the end of `map`.

Answer (score 2):

I can provide the solution with jquery.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

As argument you should define your cell, in your case it would be  `extras`. Try to give yours `roomstable.cell(closestRow,3)`. In my case was `$('#dt').find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(0)`

```js
$(function(){
  var table =  $('#dt').DataTable();
    
   arr_ids($('#dt').find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(0)); 
})

function arr_ids(celll) {
    
    var ar = [];
    
    celll.find('span').each(function(){
        if ($(this).data('id')) {
            ar.push($(this).data('id'));
        }
    });
    
    alert(ar);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
            
<table id="dt">
    <thead>
        <th>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>ccccccccccccccccccccc&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <span class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-room="1910" data-id="1" disabled>
                    <strong>unimportant description</strong>
                </span>
                <span class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-room="1945" data-id="13" disabled>
                    <strong>unimportant description</strong>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <th>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>ccccccccccccccccccccc</th>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Perhaps you would use an id of the table instead of  ```roomstable```